# Volo.Abp.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore Encountered a Date Time type issue when accessing PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, abp

When I referred to the AuthServer module using ABP, I injected the `AbpIdentityEntityFrameworkCoreModule`, and encountered an error An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Volo' when initializing data Abb Identity EntityFrameworkCore Identity DbContext '

> System InvalidCastException: Out of the range of DateTime (year must be between 1 and 9999)
> --->System ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Ticks must be between DateTime MinValue Ticks and DateTime MaxValue Ticks (Parameter 'tickets')
> At System DateTime ThrowTicksOutOfRange()
> At NpgSQL Internal TypeHandlers DateTimeHandlers DateTimeUtils ReadDateTime (NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, DateTimeKind kind)
> ---End of inner exception stack trace---
> At NpgSQL Internal TypeHandlers DateTimeHandlers DateTimeUtils ReadDateTime (NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, DateTimeKind kind)
> At NpgSQL Internal TypeHandlers DateTimeHandlers TimestampTzHandler Read (NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 len, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
> At NpgSQL NpgsqlDataReader GetFieldValue [T] (Int32 ordinal)
> At lambda_ Met。

I have rewritten the method configureServices in the AuthServerModule and added

```
AppContext SetSwitch ("NpgSQL. Enabling LegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
AppContext SetSwitch ("NpgSQL. DisableDateTimeInfinityConversions", true);
```

But still reporting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your EntityFramework project, you should update 2 places:

1-) *EntityFrameworkCore/MyProjectNameDbContextFactory.cs (add the line in the CreateDbContext method)*:

```cs
public MyProjectNameDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
        //add the below line
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
        
        //...
}
```

2-) *EntityFrameworkCore/MyProjectNameEntityFrameworkCoreModule.cs(add the line in the PreConfigureServices method)*:

```cs
public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
        //add the below line
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

        //...
}
```

Check the PR  for more info -> https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/11871