# Compatibility between EF Core 6 and Postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Iteration context type `Typhoon.AuthServer.EntityFrameworkCore.AuthServerDbContext`.

When I query using the database context, the database throws an exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: out of date time range (year must be between 1 and 9999),

I have set in the Main function.

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch ("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", True)  
AppContext.SetSwitch ("Npgsql.DisableDateTimeInfinityConversions", True);
```

However, the query still throws the above exception.

Comment: [Again?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77643374/861716)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Volo.Abp.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore Encountered a Date Time type issue when accessing PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77643374/volo-abp-identity-entityframeworkcore-encountered-a-date-time-type-issue-when-ac)